# I am working with preferences in my android application but i cant seem to get to store and retrieve values

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am fetching values from a number of text fields and storing their values in the corresponding preference values in my preference file. I dont know wat i am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View source) {
    switch(source.getId())
    {
    case R.id.imageButtonNext:
        String longitude=String.valueOf(editTextLongitude.getText());
        String latitude=String.valueOf(editTextLatitude.getText());
        String currentTime=String.valueOf(textViewCurrentTime.getText());
        String agentNo=String.valueOf(editTextAgentno.getText());
        String description=String.valueOf(editTextDescription.getText());
        String mobile_number=String.valueOf(editTextMobileNo.getText());
        moredetails=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=moredetails.edit();
        editor.putString("latitude",latitude);
        editor.putString("longitude",longitude);
        editor.putString("currentTime",currentTime);
        editor.putString("agentNo",agentNo);
        editor.putString("description",description);
        editor.putString("mobileNo",mobile_number);

        String lat=moredetails.getString("latitude","");
        Toast.makeText(CurrentLocation.this,lat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }   
}
```

PREFERENCE FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:key="latitude" android:title="@string/latitudeString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/longitudeString" android:title="@string/longitudeString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/agentNoString" android:title="@string/agentNoString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/assistantNameString" android:title="@string/assistantNameString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/mobilenoString" android:title="@string/mobilenoString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/cashFloatString" android:title="@string/cashFloatString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/efloatString" android:title="@string/efloatString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/posterAString" android:title="@string/posterAString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/posterBString" android:title="@string/posterBString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/smexnoString" android:title="@string/smexnoString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="@string/trainingString" android:title="@string/trainingString"></Preference>
    <Preference android:key="currentTime" android:title="currentTime"></Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it seems like you should be using a database for most of these instead of "preferences".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call:

```
editor.commit();
```

after making your changes to commit and store them.

You might also want to look at [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) as this provides an awful lot of functionality out-of-the-box.